# How to connect a date with data on a second tab in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am wanting to know how to connect data with a date on another tab.

on the first tab I have the date using =TODAY() in cell A1, then in cell A3 I have Passenger numbers.. On the second tab I have every date listed in the year with passenger information under each date. I am wanting to know if there was a formula I could use to connect the data with the date so that when I change the date on tab 1 it will update the information from tab 2.

trying to make it easier to be able to search for information, instead of having to scroll down to find it in excel you just type in the date you want and all the information will be provided

thanks brooke

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table to report on the data in the second tab, but you need a suitable data layout for that (one record per row, no blank rows).

It may be possible to use formulas to populate the table on the first sheet, but if there are more than one rows with the same date, a pivot table is easier.

As an alternative to scrolling, you can also use the filter features right in the table on the second sheet, without creating a special report on another sheet.

It depends very much on what level of convenience you are after, how the data is structured and how much work you want to put in.

Comment: Thanks! It is quite a detailed excel document and hard to explain but I will give a pivot table a go!